# Problem with MySql starting while booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, mysql, 21.04

when I try to start the system, I got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K7Mn.jpg) after the BIOS screen.

It seems that MySql services can't load at start and the whole system got stuck.

Sometimes nothing appears on screen but a blinking underscore in infinite loop.

I can't open terminal in any way (Shift or Ctrl+Alt+...) and I can't boot system in any way.

Can you help me finding the solution?

Comment: Try booting in recovery mode and check the logs for `mysql.service`

Comment: Shift button at start does nothing

Comment: A good deal more information will be required to work out the issue. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the full version of Ubuntu that you're running (1) which version of MySQL you are running (2) is this a WSL, VM, or bare-metal installation? (3) the errors reported in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` (4) the errors reported in `/var/log/syslog`. With this, it will be much more likely that someone can offer a solution. Otherwise, all we'll be doing is guessing and wasting time 